# Search/browse my own questions easily

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions

I have asked more than 100 questions on SO. The problem with asking so many questions is that it's sometimes very hard to navigate to the question I want.

Is there any way to improve the interface further?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

have you tried using the advanced search options to scope to your user id?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: Also, [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/131059/advanced-search-for-answers-posted-to-your-questions) to search *answers* to your questions. Not possible with advanced search as yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you're logged in to your account, you can use this query from the [list of advanced search options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

> **user:me**

Answer (score 2):

## `user:me is:question "search term here"`

#### [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)