# Just Search my own Questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, search

I often find myself needing the answer to a question was mentioned in the answers to one of my other questions.  Just searching the main site gives too many false positives.

Is there a way to just search my own questions?

Comment: and another one: [Search/browse my own questions easily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13424/search-browse-my-own-questions-easily)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, there is. Just add `user:me is:question "search term here"` to the search field and you're set ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10934/search-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/11334#11334) - [*handy link*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame)).

Perhaps this question can be rephrased and become a feature request: I observe that the [search options page](https://stackoverflow.com/search) does not list this keyword, while it obviously should.

Comment: It does: it's the first item listed under "Advanced Super Ninja Search Options".

Comment: @Æther: I noticed that line, of course, but that's not what I meant. Typing my ID is really not the same as simply typing `me`. It takes more time and is less user friendly.

Comment: _"The search options page does not list this [user:me] keyword, while it obviously should"_: In the meantime, it has been added there. Shows as "Author user:me (yours)" under "Advanced Search Tips".