# I've asked 600 questions, how do I search through my questions easily?

Tags: support, questions, search

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Searching for a particular user’s questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38778/searching-for-a-particular-users-questions)
>   [Search/ Browse My Own Questions Easily.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13424/search-browse-my-own-questions-easily)
>   [How can I search within my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27487/how-can-i-search-within-my-own-questions)

I've asked 600 questions, how do I search through my questions easily?

Comment: to meta we go...

Comment: For the record, using search to find an advanced search term in the body of a question is an exercise in futility... but thankfully the Related list has some: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27487/how-can-i-search-within-my-own-questions and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34620/just-search-my-own-questions

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13424/search-browse-my-own-questions-easily and also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff

Comment: thanks for the record please erase the record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the search box, like this:

```
user:me +querysubject1 +querysubject2 +...
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `tag-cloud` for my questions. also allow me to filter through tags like

> https://stackoverflow.com/myQuestions/tagged/php+javascript

Comment: Have you looked at your profile?

Comment: but that's for one level only. what if you have 600 questions all are for PHP? how do you traverse?

There is no way you can add second level filter like `php+javascript`

Comment: @ankit search for `user:me [php] [javascript]`

Comment: If you want a tag cloud, you are more than welcome to check out stackapps.com and use the API :)

Comment: well i forgot.. all of us here are geeks :P

wouldn't it be great - on the search page (when i come by clicking a tag on my profile page) there shld be a tag-cloud for second level filtering.. and so on? This should be build from the displayed result space.

Comment: @Ankit Suggestions for features just don't belong as answers. We try to be professionals here, otherwise it will just end up being another Yahoo!Answers. Comments are an okay place for suggestions, or to start a question of your own with it.